# multilist = [[0 for col in range(colNum)]for row in range(rowNum)]

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone please elaborate how it is functioning?

Like I am taking a value `(3,3)`

`colNum` is 3 and `rowNum` is 3.

Comment: look into `list comprehensions`. It's like a nested for loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
multilist = [[0 for col in range(colNum)] for row in range(rowNum)]
```

prints '0' in specified number of columns and rows.

ex: if colNum is 4 and rowNum is 4... then you will notice a multilist like below.

[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]

Here in the list comprehension statement the syntax is

```
[[output_expression for _ in (set of columns to iterate)] for _ in (set of rows to iterate)]
```

Now another example, in which your **output_expression** is adding **row index** and **column index**

```
multilist = [[col+row for col in range(4)] for row in range(4)]
```

and the output is

[[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6]]

Answer (score 2):

```
def print_multilist(rowNum, colNum):
    multilist = [[0 for col in range(colNum)]for row in range(rowNum)]
    print(multilist)

print_multilist(3,3)#prints [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
print_multilist(2,2) #prints [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

The above line is a list comprehension. It is equivalent to as follows without using list comprehensions

```
def print_multilist(rowNum, colNum):
    multilist = []
    for row in range(rowNum):
        multilist.append([])
        for col in range(colNum):
            multilist[row].append(0)
    print(multilist)

print_multilist(3,3) #prints [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
print_multilist(2,2) #prints [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

List comprehensions are very useful in python, as they decreases the code written like above. For more information about list comprehensions, Visit [link](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)